# Margins not rendering correctly due to enlarged text

Tags: html, css

I am having difficulty understanding what is incorrect with my code. I have only 1 week experience with CSS so please bear with me.

When the text is small, **the like this review button** aligns exactly 35px from the gray container just below it. When the text is large the button does not conform anymore.

What I'm hoping for is **a solution that will cause the table row to just expand and the button will conform to 35px above when the text is large.**

Here is an image of when the text is small. Everything seems to work fine. Note that the button is exactly 35px from the gray container just below it.

[image]

So here's where the problem relies. When I have massive amounts of text, this is the end result. If you notice, **the button now sits on the gray container instead of 35px above it**.

[image]

Now that you understand the problem, here is my current code:

CSS:

```
    @CHARSET "UTF-8";
    .page {
     position: relative;
     background-color: #ffffff;
     width: 1200px;
     margin: 0px auto;
     box-sizing: border-box;
     border-left: 1px solid #d0d0d0;
     border-right: 1px solid #d0d0d0;   
    }
    table {
     border:0px;
     width:100% 
    }
    table.reviewsouter .reviewleft{
     width:800px;
     position:absolute;
    }
    table.reviewsouter .reviewright{
     width:400px;
     vertical-align:top;
    }
    #reviewspotlight {
     position: relative;
     background-color:#000000;
     height:146px;
     z-index:19997;
     font-family: DinWebCond, Sans-serif;
     color:#ffffff;
    }
    #reviewspotlight a:hover{
        color:#e85a06
    }
    #reviewspotlight img.spotlightphoto{
        position:relative;
        width:260px;
        height:146px;
        left:-1px;
        margin:0px;
        display:inline-block;
    }
    #reviewspotlight td a{
        color:#ffffff;
        font: 32px/32px DinWebCond,Sans-serif;
        border:none;
        text-decoration: none;  
    }
    #reviewspotlight td h1{
        margin:10px 0px 0px 15px;
        color:#ffffff;
        font:32px/32px DinWebCond, Sans-serif;
        font-weight:inherit;
    }
    #reviewspotlight td div.reviewrating
    {
        position:relative;
        margin: 2px 0px 0px 0px;    
    }
    #reviewspotlight td div.reviewrating img.reviewstars{
        /**position:absolute;*/
        display:inline-block;
        width:125px;
        height:21px;
        border:none;
        margin:0px 0px 5px 15px;
    }
    #reviewspotlight td div.phone{
      position: relative;
      height: 18px;
      font: 14px/14px Arial, Helvetica, Sans-serif;
      padding: 0px 0px 0px 22px;
      margin: 0px 15px;
      background: url(data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhEgASALMAADMzAJmZZv///8/Pz87OzszMzJmZmWlpaWZmZjMzMwAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAACwAAAAAEgASAAAEWFDISatNiCaVjBWIonhSsHEEZYgKYK3KMLEiiUkFN9OFUJyelY3V0ygkOh+xkstsJqeERWeQ7hTFSbYCw34+oeS3chpJNodxmSbaUsJssSXHto4F1dp9HwEAOw==) 0px 0px no-repeat;
    }
    #reviewspotlight td h2{
        font:14px/14px AdlWebNorm, Serif;
        margin:5px 0px 0px 15px;
    }
    #reviews {
      position: relative;
      background-color:#ffffff;
      color:#000000;
      border-right:1px solid #d0d0d0;
    }
    #reviews table tr.reviewuserinfo {
      background-color:#f0f0f0;
      height:60px;
      border-left:1px solid #d0d0d0;      
    }
    #reviews table tr.reviewuserinfo img.avatar{
      position:relative;
      width:40px;
      height:40px;
      margin:10px;
      display: inline-block;
      vertical-align: middle;
    }
    #reviews table tr.reviewuserinfo div {
      display:block
    }
    #reviews table tr.reviewuserinfo a {
        color:#e85a06;
        font-family:DinWebCond,Sans-serif;
        border:none;
        text-decoration:none;
    }
    #reviews table tr.reviewuserdata {
      background-color:#ffffff;
      height: 315px;
      border-left:1px solid #ffffff;
      vertical-align: top;  
    }
    #reviews table td h2 {
        position:relative;
        display:inline-block;
        white-space:nowrap;
        font:27px/27px DinWebCond,Sans-serif;
        margin:0px;
        text-transform:uppercase;
        /**padding:20px 0px 9px 15px;*/
        /**padding-top:20px;*/
        /**padding-left:20px;*/
    }
    #reviews table td h2 img.stars {
        position:absolute;
        margin-left:10px;
        margin-top:1px;
        display:inline-block;
    }
    #reviews table td h2 span.rating{
        position:relative;
        margin-left:145px;
        display:inline-block;
        color:#e85a06;
        font-weight:bold;   
    }

    table.reviewchart {
        position:relative;
        display:inline-block;
        white-space:nowrap;
        border-collapse: collapse;
        font:14px/14px DinWebCond,Sans-serif;
        margin:0px;
        text-transform:uppercase;
        /**padding:20px 0px 9px 15px;*/
        padding-top:20px;
        padding-left:20px;  
    }
    table.reviewchart td.reviewlabel{
        /**padding-top:15px;*/
        padding-bottom:15px;
    }
    #reviews.dl {
        position:relative;
        margin: 15px 15px 15px 15px;
    }
    #reviews dt {
        position:relative;
        display:inline-block;
        float:left;
        width:165px;
        /**text-align:right;*/
        pointer-events:none;
        margin:0px;
        padding:3px 0px 2px 0px;
        z-index:2;
        text-align:right;
    }
    #reviews dd {
        position:relative;
        display:block;
        margin:0px;
        padding:3px 0px 2px 0px;
        z-index:1;
        font-weight:700;
        color:#e85a06;
    }
    #reviews dd .bar {
        position:relative;
        display:inline-block;
        width:50px;
        height:15px;
        margin:1px 20px -1px 20px;
    }
    #reviews dd .bar div {
        position:absolute;
        left:0px;
        top:0px;
        height:100%;
        background-color:#4ac4f3;
        border-top-right-radius:3px;
        border-bottom-right-radius:3px;
    }
    #reviews table .comment{
        margin:25px 0px 0px 25px;
        font:14px/20px Arial, Helvetica, Sans-serif;
    }
    #reviews table .reviewusermetadata{
        padding-right:15px;
        font:12px/12px Arial, Helvetica, Sans-serif;
    }
    .share_location{
        position:relative;
        margin:20px 15px 0px 20px;
    }
    .ad_location{
        position:relative;
        margin:20px 15px 0px 20px;
    }
    button {
        display: inline-block;
        outline: none;
        font: 14px/14px DinWebCond, Sans-serif;
        color: #808080;
        border: 1px solid #c0c0c0;
        background-color: #f0f0f0;
        border-radius: 3px;
        cursor: pointer;
        margin-right: 10px;
        padding: 9px 10px 7px 10px;
        text-transform: uppercase;
        text-shadow: 0px 1px 0px #ffffff;
        box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 0px #ffffff;
    }
```

HTML:

```
    <tr class="reviewuserdata">         
    <td colspan="2">
    <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="reviewchart">
    <tr><td><h2>Overall Rating <img class="stars" src="/act/stars/{./rating}/large" /> <span class="rating"><xsl:value-of select="./rating"/></span></h2></td></tr>
    <tr>
    <td>
    <dl style="margin-top:5px">
    <dt><span>QUALITY OF THE DANCERS</span></dt>
    <dd><div class="bar"><div style="width:{./qualitydancers div 5*100}%"></div></div><xsl:value-of select="./qualitydancers"/></dd>
    <dt><span>PRIVATE DANCES, VALUE FOR MONEY</span></dt>
    <dd><div class="bar"><div style="width:{./privatedances div 5*100}%"></div></div><xsl:value-of select="./privatedances"/></dd>                              
    <dt><span>OVERALL HOSPITALITY</span></dt>
    <dd><div class="bar"><div style="width:{./hospitality div 5*100}%"></div></div><xsl:value-of select="./hospitality"/></dd>
    <dt><span>GUEST TO DANCER RATIO</span></dt>
    <dd><div class="bar"><div style="width:{./guestdancerratio div 5*100}%"></div></div><xsl:value-of select="./guestdancerratio"/></dd>
    <dt><span>VARIETY OF DANCERS</span></dt>
    <dd><div class="bar"><div style="width:{./varietydancers div 5*100}%"></div></div><xsl:value-of select="./varietydancers"/></dd>
    <dt><span>VALUE FOR MONEY, COVER CHARGE</span></dt>
    <dd><div class="bar"><div style="width:{./covercharge div 5*100}%"></div></div><xsl:value-of select="./covercharge"/></dd>
    <dt><span>VALUE FOR MONEY, DRINKS</span></dt>
    <dd><div class="bar"><div style="width:{./drinks div 5*100}%"></div></div><xsl:value-of select="./drinks"/></dd>
    <dt><span>VALUE FOR MONEY, FOOD</span></dt>
    <dd><div class="bar"><div style="width:{./food div 5*100}%"></div></div><xsl:value-of select="./food"/></dd>
    <dt><span>OVERALL ATMOSPHERE</span></dt>
    <dd><div class="bar"><div style="width:{./atmosphere div 5*100}%"></div></div><xsl:value-of select="./atmosphere"/></dd>
    <dt><span>SOUND SYSTEM AND DJ</span></dt>
    <dd><div class="bar"><div style="width:{./sound div 5*100}%"></div></div><xsl:value-of select="./sound"/></dd>
    </dl>                           
    </td>
    </tr>
    </table>
    </td>
    <td colspan="1">
    <div class="comment" style="margin-right:15px">
    <xsl:value-of select="./comment"/>
    <div style="float:right;margin-top:185px">
    <button style="">Like This Review</button>
    </div>
    </div>  
    </td>
    </tr>
```

Comment: Just add a margin to the button. Judging by the pictures is looks like when there's the gap under the button, it's just the left side that's affecting the height. And there's no margin for the right side, as there's no gap when the left side is lower than the right side.

Comment: Add some padding-bottom or margin bottom to the div that contains the button.

Answer (score 1):

Add `margin-bottom: 35px` to the CSS for the `button`.

The reason why you see the button touch the next thing is simply that there is no bottom margin specified for it anywhere.

**Also**, please do not mix inline styles with CSS. Just move the inline styles to the CSS.